# Debugging Challenge in regards to TreeSet

Tags: java, twos-complement

So this was going to be my question, but I actually figured out the problem while I was writing it.  Perhaps this will be useful for others (I will remove the question if it's a duplicate or is deemed inappropriate for this site).  I know of two possible solutions to my problem, but perhaps someone will come up with a better one than I thought of.

I don't understand why [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) isn't removing the first element here.  The size of the my `TreeSet` is supposed to stay bounded, but appears to grow without bound.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code:

This code resides inside of a double for loop.  `NUM_GROUPs` is a `static final int` which is set to `100`.  `newGroups` is a `TreeSet<TeamGroup>` object which is initialized (with no elements) before the double for loop (the variables `group` and `team` are from the two for-each loops).

```
final TeamGroup newGroup = new TeamGroup(group, team);
newGroups.add(newGroup);
System.err.println("size of newGroups: " + newGroups.size());
if (newGroups.size() > NUM_GROUPS) {
    System.err.println("removing first from newGroups");
    newGroups.remove(newGroups.first());
    System.err.println("new size of newGroups: "
        + newGroups.size());
}
```

I included my debugging statements to show that the problem really does appear to happen.  I get the following types of output:

```
size of newGroups: 44011
removing first from newGroups
new size of newGroups: 44011
```

You see that although the `if` statement is clearly being entered, the size of the `TreeSet<TeamGroup> teamGroups` isn't being decremented.  It would seem to me that the only way for this to happen is if the `remove` call doesn't remove anything--but how can it *not* remove something from a call to `first()` which should *definitely* be an element in the `TreeSet`?

Here is the `compareTo` method in my `TeamGroup` class (`score` is an `int` which could very reasonably be the same for many different `TeamGroup` objects hence why I use the `R_ID` field as a tie-breaker):

```
public int compareTo(TeamGroup o) {
    // sorts low to high so that when you pop off of the TreeSet object, the
    // lowest value gets popped off (and keeps the highest values).
    if (o.score == this.score)
        return this.R_ID - o.R_ID;
    return this.score - o.score;
}
```

Here is the `equals` method for my `TeamGroup` class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    return this.R_ID == ((TeamGroup) o).R_ID;
}
```

...I'm not worried about a `ClassCastException` here because this is specifically pertaining to my above problem where I never try to compare a `TeamGroup` object with anything but another `TeamGroup` object--and this is definitely *not* the problem (at least not a `ClassCastException` problem).

The `R_ID`'s are supposed to be unique and I guarantee this by the following:

```
private static final double WIDTH = (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE
        - (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
private static final Map<Integer, Integer> MAPPED_IDS = 
    new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(50000);
...
public final int R_ID = TeamGroup.getNewID();
...
private static int getNewID() {
    int randID = randID();
    while (MAPPED_IDS.get(randID) != null) {
        randID = randID();
    }

    MAPPED_IDS.put(randID, randID);

    return randID;
}

private static int randID() {
    return (int) (Integer.MIN_VALUE + Math.random() * WIDTH);
}
```

Comment: This is a well-known problem with implementing `compareTo` ... but I couldn't spot a suitable Q&A as the definitive duplicate.  (If someone else can, please do so.)

Comment: @StephenC What is the well-known problem you are alluding to?  Like I said, I know what the problem is and it _is_ in the `compareTo` method but it doesn't really have anything to do with the `compareTo` method per se.  The true problem resides in _both_ the `compareTo` method _and_ the fact that I'm using a sorted set.

Comment: No.  The problem is that your `compareTo` is implemented incorrectly.  And it is well known that implementing it *that way* is incorrect.

Comment: @StephenC Well I obviously don't disagree with you there (the `compareTo` method _is_ definitely incorrectly implemented), but why does this lead to the problem I had (and I realize that your answer touched on why).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        return this.R_ID - o.R_ID;
```

It should be:

```
        return Integer.compare(this.R_ID, o.R_ID);
```

Taking the difference of two `int` or `Integer` values works if the values are both guaranteed to be non-negative.  However, in your example, you are using ID values across the entire range of `int` / `Integer` and that means that the subtraction can lead to overflow ... and an incorrect result for `compareTo`.

The incorrect implementation leads to situations where the `compareTo` method is not reflexive; i.e. integers `I1`, `I2` and `I3` where the `compareTo` method says that  `I1 < I2` and `I2 < I3`, but also `I3 < I1`.  When you plug this into `TreeSet`, elements get inserted into the tree in the wrong place, and strange behaviours happen.  Precisely what is happening is hard to predict - it will depend on the objects that are inserted, and the *order* they are inserted.

> `TreeSet.first()` should definitely return an object which belongs to the set, right?

Probably ...

> So then why can it not remove this object?

Probably because it can't find it ... because of the broken compareTo.

To understand what exactly is going on, you would been to single step through the TreeSet code, etcetera.

Comment: That's sort of the one of the solutions I had in mind (although I was thinking to compare it myself with `if-else` statements...but your way is much cleaner).  It would be nice to explain why my (original) way didn't work correctly.

Comment: You definitely caught the error, but why does this error cause the behavior?  That is actually something I don't have an explanation for.  `TreeSet.first()` should definitely return an object which belongs to the set, right?  So then why can it not remove this object?  (I suspect it has something to do with how the `TreeSet` object searches for elements, but I'm not sure).

Comment: Thanks for the extra details.